# How can I use publicEncrypt() in react native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, encryption

currently I need to use `publicEncrpyt()` Method to encrypt buffer with public key(pem file).
but react native is not supporting 'crypto' library because It is not running on Node.js.

I checked 3rd party libraries but I wasn't able to find any method which is exactly same thing as `publicEncrypt()`.

[Here is publicEncrypt method doc](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-crypto-publicencrypt-method/)

Does anyone have a same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just save it here.

A package to support for `publicEncrypt` method:
https://github.com/margelo/react-native-quick-crypto

`v0.5.0` supports `react-native` < 0.69

`v0.6.1` supports `react-native` 0.69+